# Dynamically resize Facebook Like Box - responsive change of data-width="{n}"

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, dynamically-generated

The Facebook code:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://stackoverflow.com/" data-width="160" data-height="100" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="false" data-stream="false" data-show-border="false"></div>
```

I am trying to **change data-width="{n}"** and/or **data-height="{n}"** dynamically on screen size change (smartphone/tablet orientation change) using either javascript or CSS media queries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding this to your css code:

```
.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-like-box, .fb-like-box iframe[style] {width:  100% !important;display:block;z-index:2000;position:relative}
.fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe span[style], .fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box iframe  span[style] {width: 100% !important;display:block;z-index:2000;position:relative}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The solution works well, without need for js. Great solution, thank you! I see that you are overriding the default width on the fb-like-box and the span inside. Including the fb-comments class had any particular reason in my case or just makes the solution more general?

Comment: Glad to help. It's a general solution for all fb social plugins.

Comment: great code, can you suggest some similar solution for setting dynamic height? Because by using your css, the like box is somewhat clipped at the bottom.

Comment: hey @SaumilSoni, can you share a link?

Comment: LOL, no worries @ManishShrivastava